# adding a DropDownList on asp.net mvc containing a specific choices

Tags: asp.net-mvc

adding a DropDownList on asp.net MVC containing specific choices, when the user chooses, his choice will be saved in the database under his user name on the registration page. I have tried to add a new cell in the table of my database and tried some codes but it doesn't work with me. 
 my website has 2 user model one of them is metadata and reset password model, one table and one database for now. I wish to add a new cell in the table called college the student will choose one of the colleges on the DropDownList and his choice will be saved under his user name.

for anyone who could help me, I can send my whole project as 1 zip file.

Comment: You need to post some code for others to be able to help you.

Comment: I have solved it by using Radi Button but still, I need to the DropDownList to let the voter choose who will vote to also I want each voter to vote only once and vote for a person who is in the same college of the voter I will send the whole code now

Comment: user controller class

Comment: (too long by 9389 characters) that is only the user controller code how can i post it

Comment: You must post the code in the question.